# What null hypothesis test is suitable for percentage dependent variable?

Tags: regression, anova

What null hypothesis test is suitable for a dataset with the independent variable of three concentrations of chemicals and dependent variable of percentage of leaves affected by the chemical upon spraying?

Comment: A hypothesis about zero (or some other value) percentange (equivalent to a ratio test).